# Concatenate string literal with char literal

Tags: c, string, macros, char, concatenation

I want to concat a string literal and char literal. Being syntactically incorrect, `"abc" 'd' "efg"` renders a compiler error:

> x.c:4:24: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'd'

By now I have to use snprift (needlessly), despite the value of string literal and the char literal being know at compile time.

I tried

```
#define CONCAT(S,C) ({ \
    static const char *_r = { (S), (C) }; \
    _r; \
})
```

but it does not work because the null terminator of `S` is not stripped. (Besides of giving compiler warnings.)

Is there a way to write a macro to use

- `"abc" MACRO('d') "efg"` or
- `MACRO1(MACRO2("abc", 'd'), "efg")` or
- `MACRO("abc", 'd', "efg")` ?

In case someone asks why I want that: The char literal comes from a library and I need to print the string out as a status message.

Comment: I do not want to *want to* use sprintf or any runtime functions. Please do not put any answers that employ runtime method calls.

Comment: If the literal comes from a library, how are you accessing it?  Is it a macro provided by the library header file?

Comment: Yes, It comes from a header file.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140446/macro-string-literal-from-char-literal

Answer (score 7):

If you can live with the single quotes being included with it, you could use stringification:

```
#define SOME_DEF 'x'

#define STR1(z) #z
#define STR(z) STR1(z)
#define JOIN(a,b,c) a STR(b) c

int main(void)
{
  const char *msg = JOIN("Something to do with ", SOME_DEF, "...");

  puts(msg);

  return 0;
}
```

Depending on the context that may or may not be appropriate, but as far as convincing it to actually be a string literal buitl this way, it's the only way that comes to mind without formatting at runtime.

Comment: Why not use directly STR1 in the concatenation, like JOIN(a,b,c) a STR1(b) c ? Instead of using the sub-macro STR() ?

Comment: @Luciano Because then it will show up as *"Something to do with SOME_DEF..."*

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It uses the C macro trick of double macros so the macro argument has the chance to expand before it is stringified.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C d
#define S "This is a string that contains the character "
#define STR(s) #s
#define XSTR(s) STR(s)

const char* str = S XSTR(C);

int main()
{
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a GCC-specific solution that I don't like too much, as one cannot use `CONCAT` nestedly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONCAT(S1,C,S2) ({                        \
    static const struct __attribute__((packed)) { \
        char s1[sizeof(S1) - 1];                  \
        char c;                                   \
        char s2[sizeof(S2)];                      \
    } _r = { (S1), (C), (S2) };                   \
    (const char *) &_r;                           \
})

int main(void) {
    puts(CONCAT ("abc", 'd', "efg"));
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/lzEAn

Comment: Good idea, but compiling with gcc with the `-pedantic` option gives the warnings "array initialized from parenthesized string constant" and "ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions".

Answer (score 2):

C will only let you concatenate string literals. Actually, there's nothing wrong with `snprintf()`. You could also use `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(dest, str1);
dest[strlen(dest)] = c;
strcpy(dest + strlen(dest) + 1, str2);
```

You could also use a giant `switch` statement to overcome this limitation:

```
switch(c) {
    case 'a':
        puts("part1" "a" "part2");
        break;
    case 'b':
        puts("part1" "b" "part2");
        break;

    /* ... */

    case 'z':
        puts("part1" "z" "part2");
        break;
}
```

...but I refuse to claim any authorship.

To put it short, just stick with `snprintf()`.

Comment: The thing is that I do not *want to* use snprintf or strcpy. It is more of a philosophical question than a beginners question …

Comment: kay: Ah, I see... Good luck! ;)  BTW, what's wrong with `printf("part1 %c part2\n", c);`?

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with printf. I just wanted to know if it was possible to get the whole string at compile time w/o any runtime activity. There is nothing at stake of having such a macro or not. You see … it's a philosophical question. ;)