# macro: string literal from char literal

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way in C to create a string literal from a character literal, using a macro?

for example I have

```
'a'
```

and I want to create the string literal

```
"a"
```

---

To clarify the question:

```
#define A 'a'

write(fd, "x=" CHAR2STRING(A) "\n", 4);
```

My question is how to define the macro CHAR2STRING

Comment: An inline-macro? (no var decls)? I'm curious as well, as one is two `char` wide, the other is one. Where might you suggest the *second* char (the terminator) be stored? Not even going to one eval'ing as an address, which  would still need to be solved.

Comment: @WhozCraig - It should be evaluated at compile time. I expect it to be stored the same way as if I had used "a" directly in my code (and not instructed the compiler to generate it).

Comment: Then I don't see it happening, but I'll be genuinely curious if someone comes up with a way of doing so. (too late, and out-of-caffeine for me to gel on it right now).

Comment: Is there some reason it's not possible to use fprintf or similar, along the lines of `fprintf(fd, "x=%c\n", A);` ?

Comment: And the `A` macro must be a char literal and cannot be something else, like 97 or 0x61? Can't you do things the other way round by making `A` a string literal and writing a `STRING2CHAR(A)` macro for the other uses of `A`?

Comment: The code above was just an illustration. I could use sprintf in the real code but I was wondering if what I'm asking is possible. Also, I'm concerned about performance so I prefer not to use sprintf.

Comment: I think this is impossible. However you could define `a` and then generate from that both `'a'` and `"a"`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I was thinking about this as an alternative, but couldn't get it to work (`"a"` works, but how to make `'a'`?). If you can, I think that is an answer (I believe what OP exactly wants is impossible, so we need alternatives anyway and this is one).

Comment: @mafso `*"a"` instead of `'a'`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Ah, I see, thanks. At martinkunev: Does this answer your question?

Comment: @mafso - Yes, from all the comments I pretty much figured out what is possible and what not and how to achieve what I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*–Summary of the comments to the question–*

This seems impossible to achieve. As an alternative, the string literal could be defined and a `STRING2CHAR` macro be written instead:

```
#define A "a"
#define STRING2CHAR(s) (*(s))
write(fd, "x=" A "\n", 4);
putchar(STRING2CHAR(A));
```

or

```
#define A a
#define XSTR(s) #s
#define SYM2CHAR(sym) (*XSTR(sym))
#define SYM2STRING(sym) XSTR(sym)
```

The expression `*"a"` isn't a compile-time constant (so e.g. it cannot be used as an initializer for an object with non-automatic storage duration, a non-VLA array length, a `case` label, or a bit-field width), though compilers should be able to evaluate it at compile-time (tested with Gcc and Clang).

---

<sup>Suggested by [M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm) and [Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
#define A 'a'
#define X(macro) #macro
#define CHAR2STRING(macro) X(macro)

printf("%s\n", CHAR2STRING(A));
```

you will get 'a' instead of a, but maybe thats ok for you.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm quite late to the party, here's a solution I came up with for ASCII (7 bits) characters:

```
#define CHAR2STR(c) ((char*[]){ \
    "\0", "\1", "\2", "\3", "\4", "\5", "\6", "\a", \
    "\b", "\t", "\n", "\v", "\f", "\r", "\16", "\17", \
    "\20", "\21", "\22", "\23", "\24", "\25", "\26", "\27", \
    "\30", "\31", "\32", "\33", "\34", "\35", "\36", "\37", \
    " ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", \
    "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", \
    "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", \
    "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", \
    "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", \
    "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", \
    "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", \
    "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "\\", "]", "^", "_", \
    "`", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", \
    "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", \
    "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", \
    "x", "y", "z", "{", "|", "}", "~", "\177", \
})[c]
```

This can be extended to the full ASCII table with `"\180", "\181" ...` (all numbers are octals, so no `\178`!), but I don't really think it would be useful, considering it's a MACRO.
The trick works thanks to an anonymous string array ("table") initialized in place, which should be optimized by the compiler automatically (if the character is known).

Comment: gcc error: test.c:3:21: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
    3 | #define CHAR2STR(c) ((char*[]){ \

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but it works:

```
#define STRING_ME(tgt, ch) tgt[0]=ch;tgt[1]='\0'
```

Assumes tgt has space for 2 chars. Perhaps you could give an example what you want it to look like?