# Create string in C where first character is string length

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

This question is related to [Concatenate string literal with char literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912214/concatenate-string-literal-with-char-literal), but is slightly more complex.

I would like to create a string literal, where the first character of the string is the length of the string, and the second character is a constant. This is how it is being done currently:

```
const char myString[] = 
{
    0x08,
    SOME_8_BIT_CONSTANT,
    'H',
    'e',
    'l',
    'l',
    'o',
    0x00
};
```

Ideally, I would like to replace it with something like:

```
const char myString[] = BUILD_STRING(0xAA, "Hello");
```

I tried implementing it like this:

```
#define STR2(S) #S
#define STR(S) STR2(S)
#define BUILD_STRING(C, S)  {(sizeof(S)+2), C, S}

const char myString[] = BUILD_STRING(0xAA, "Hello");
```

but it expands to:

```
const char myString[] = {(sizeof("Hello")+2), 0xAA, "Hello"};
```

and the compiler doesn't seem to like mixing numbers and strings.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hm in your example, the string length is 7, not 8.

Comment: The C preprocessor has no way to determine a string length. If you use `sizeof` you are no longer in pre-processing stage: might as well write a proper function.

Comment: like a "\pPascal String"?

Comment: @pmg Right but the OP doesn’t require this to be done at the preprocessor stage. All they require is for it to be done *at compile time*. Case in point, if there were a way of performing macro transformation from `BUILD_STRING(C, "foo");` to `{sizeof "foo" + 2, C, "foo"[0], "foo"[1], …}` then that would fulfil OP’s requirements. I don’t think there’s a way but maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: @weadhervane I would rather say that the length is 5. The rest is not the string

Comment: @pmg `sizeof` will be evaluated at compile time (except in the case of VLAs, which isn't relevant here), so it still satisfies OPs requirements.

Comment: Yes @CoffeeTableEspresso, I misinterpreted the question to find a way with the preprocessor. `sizeof` is "compiled" after that stage, but does not emit code that executes at runtime (as opposed to my suggestion of a proper function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could in-place define a structure to hold the prefix and the rest, conveniently initialize it, and then treat the whole `struct` as a `char` array (not a strict-aliasing violation because standard C lets you treat any object as a `char` array).

Technically, you're not guaranteed that the compiler won't insert padding between the prefix and the rest, but in practice you can count on it.

```
#define BUILD_STRING(C, S)  \
      ((char const*)&(struct{ char const p[2]; char const s[sizeof(S)]; })\
                            { {(sizeof(S)+2), C}, S})

const char *myString = BUILD_STRING(0xAA, "Hello");

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d, %#hhX, '%s'\n", myString[0], myString[1], myString+2);
    //PRINTS: 8, 0XAA, 'Hello'
}
```

---

Edit:

If you're paranoid about the possibility of padding, here's one way to statically assert none is inserted:

```
#define BUILD_STRING__(S)  \
      char const p[2]; char const s[sizeof(S)]
#define BUILD_STRING(C, S)  \
      ((char const*)&(struct{BUILD_STRING__(S); \
            _Static_assert(sizeof(S)+2== \
                    sizeof(struct{BUILD_STRING__(S);_Static_assert(1,"");}),""); \
        }){ {sizeof(S)+2, C}, S})
```

Alternatively, using the first version with the (nonstandard) 
`__attribute((__packed__))` should do the same.

Comment: Can you use compiler extensions for attributes to declare the struct as having packed layout?

Comment: @KonradRudolph `__attribute((__packed__))`. Sure. Seems unnecessary, though. Sane compilers don't pad if they don't need to.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It'd be more inclined to pack a static assertion in there asserting no padding (=> no nonstandard stuff).

Comment: After trying for a while to come up with a pure preprocessor way (no luck), I think this is the only way to do this at compile time. The asserts will make sure it doesn't break by mistake.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I'd be very surprised if there was another way.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso (Of course if the array can be writable you can just patch it up after initialization.)

Comment: One slight problem, the declarations are all of the form `const char myString[]` rather than `const char *myString`. How can I modify `Build_String()` accordingly?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet That might be difficult without nonstandard extensions. Why do you need that?

Comment: Because all of the definitions are in the .h file, and are already in that format. It's OK, I can just go and change those too. I was just wondering. Thanks for your cool solution.